# Does twilio allow me to send a message for a specific number(grabbed from my wordpress) on whatsapp?

Tags: wordpress, api, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I have a wordpress website, and I already created a form with "contact form 7" that allows anyone to write down his email address and click on the "request" button to receive an email with a PDF file.

Twilio is quite interesting, and I searched a lot about it, and there are a lot of tutorial online on how to create similar stuff, but not exactly what I want it to do.

I want to make a normal text box form, and ask the client to write in his/her whatsapp number.
Then after clicking a submit button, my bot or business whatsapp number automatically takes the input number of that client and send him a pdf file. I don't wanna make any conversation, I just want a PDF file sent to the number that registered for it.
I'm not sure if that is even legal or not, since anyone can type any number that my bot spams that number :D

I'm curious tho, is that possible?

Comment: To clarify--you just want to send an outbound message to a WhatsApp #?

Comment: Exactly! Just a message to be sent from my twilio whatsapp to different number obtained from my wordpress form

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That is possible! Sending a message via WhatsApp from Twilio to a different number will be the same code as if you were sending a message via Twilio SMS. [Here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) is how you would do that in the programming language of your choosing; for example, it would look like this in Node.js:

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({body: 'Hi there!', from: 'whatsapp:+YOUR-WHATSAPP-NUM', to: 'whatsapp:+NUM-TO-SEND-TO'})
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

[Here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api) are the docs to configure Twilio WhatsApp.

At the moment, only approved business accounts can use Twilio's WhatsApp API so we need  to use the [Twilio API Sandbox for WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api%23twilio-sandbox-for-whatsapp) to play around. Let's go on over to the [Sandbox in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox). To activate it we must choose a Sandbox number, agree to the terms of WhatsApp, and select Activate Sandbox.[image: Set up Twilio sandbox]

To join a Sandbox, send “join ” to your Sandbox number in WhatsApp and you should get a response confirming you’ve joined. You can follow [these instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#twilio-sandbox-for-whatsapp) to install the [WhatsApp Sandbox](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox) Channel in your account and [connect your WhatsApp account with the Sandbox](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#joining-a-sandbox).

Let me know if this helps at all!

Answer (score 0):

You do need explicit opt-in and the first outbound message must be a template.

See article below.

[Rules and Best Practices for WhatsApp Messaging on Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017773294-Rules-and-Best-Practices-for-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio)

Comment: Can the opt-in be other than an action on whatsapp? Can it be for example, a link that triggers whatsapp so it can send to the number a file?

Comment: If the WhatsApp user clicks a link (via your website) that brings up WhatsApp and then they send you a message via WhatsApp (initiates to you), then it is implied opt-out for that one-time dialog at that moment only, and you can reply.